# Returning an object of values from grouped LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have successfully got my desired output from a grouped `LINQ` statement but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

At the moment I have two elements in each group and I'm using the code below to return a list of objects with `fieldA, fieldB` values:

```
infoList.GroupBy(s => s.Name.Substring(0, s.Name.LastIndexOf("whatever")) + 1)
         .Select(grp => new { 
                              fieldA = grp.ElementAt(0).Value, 
                              fieldB = grp.ElementAt(1).Value 
                         }
          );
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: would their always be 2 elements!Are you sure about that

Comment: You could use the `First()` and the `Skip(1).First()` on the `grp`

Comment: Yes, but I would like a solution where that didn't have to be the case.

Comment: Should it return any groups that have less detail objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
infoList.GroupBy(s => s.Name.Substring(0, s.Name.LastIndexOf("whatever"),
                (key, g) => new { fieldKey= key,fieldValues = g.ToList() });
```

This is because group won't always have 2 elements with it..It's better you store those as a list